# Cannot find module 'sqlite3'

Tags: node.js, npm-install, node-sqlite3

I´m trying to migrate data to db browser, so I created a table using SQL language in my JavaScript after that I ran the file (node filename.js) and it said that cannot find sqlite3, this is strange because in my package.json file in dependencies object it's showing "sqlite3": "^3.1.13",

btw, my
node version is 12.13.0;
npm version is 6.12.0 I'm using
windows 8;

Comment: Did you `--save`?

Comment: if I Save my js file?

Comment: I already solved it changed to the latest version of sqlite3 I ran npm install https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/tarball/master @Phix,